# How to kill mySQL thread ID/Table lock

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL server that has a hung transaction:

---TRANSACTION 4DC445419, ACTIVE 11869 sec, process no 4607, OS thread id 139794812577536

I'm unable to see this transaction in the process list and have not been able to kill it.  Any ideas?

Comment: `Kill` command. But I'm not sure if you could use this since in your case the transaction is not being displayed in the process list. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html

Answer (score 0):

Log in as the super user - this is in most linux installations the user root. This will allow you to kill any processes. Or restart the server.